# Is it possible set whitelist with rate limit in traefik 1.7

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, whitelist, traefik-ingress, rate-limiting

I use traefik with k8s. In the documentation there are no examples for working with the white list. [rate limit docs](https://docs.traefik.io/v1.7/configuration/commons/#rate-limiting)

```
kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/rate-limit: |
  extractorfunc: client.ip
  rateset:
    to-back:
      period: 2s
      average: 5
      burst: 15
```

Comment: Do you want to setup a middleware for ip whitelist (https://docs.traefik.io/middlewares/ipwhitelist/#configuration-examples) or add an white-list annotation to your ingress (https://docs.traefik.io/v1.7/configuration/backends/kubernetes/#annotations) ?

Comment: @KFC_  it is not available in version 1.7

Comment: `traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range` annotation in traefik ingress is available in 1.7

Comment: @MariuszK. Do you know if it is possible to rate limit for an specific resource in the same ingress? i.e. /myapi without rate limit and /myapi/thisratelimited/. Tnx